# Why not closed serial port in destructor?

Tags: linux, qt, destructor

I use the socat for create virtual serial port:

$socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0

and just open it by my programm and stop the programm by Ctrl+c, after run again let me this message:

"Failed to open port pts/9, error: Device or resource busy"

```
#include "serport.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSerialPort serialPort;
    serialPort.setPortName("/dev/pts/9");
    serialPort.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);

    if (!serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug() << QObject::tr("Failed to open port %1, error: %2").arg(serialPort.portName()).arg(serialPort.errorString()) << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    serport port(&serialPort,&a);
    a.connect(&a, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &serialPort, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    a.connect(&a, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &port, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

serport.h

```
#ifndef SERPORT_H
#define SERPORT_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>

class serport : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit serport(QSerialPort *serialPort, QObject *parent);
    ~serport();
    QSerialPort *port;
signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // SERPORT_H
```

serport.cpp

```
#include "serport.h"
serport::serport(QSerialPort *serialPort, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent),port(serialPort){ }

serport::~serport(){
    qDebug()<<"closing";
    port->close();
}
```

How to propertly close port? Why in my program never seen the "closing" message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about quitting the process without invoking all the release handlers. More of Linux-specific rather than Qt. But you can still do something about it. Make sure to create a user handler for Ctrl-c with Qt.

[QApplication: How to shutdown gracefully on Ctrl-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300401/qapplication-how-to-shutdown-gracefully-on-ctrl-c)

Answer (score 2):

You says yourself that you "stop the programm by Ctrl+c".

By doing so you're sending a SIGINT signal to your program's process. The typical result[*] for such a signal is to terminate the process, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

The process then "die" wherever it is in its execution. In your case, most probably in its main Qt event loop. You seem to presuppose that your program would cleanly terminate, and for instance would auto-magically call all the destructors for the objects you created. This is absolutely *not* the case. The destructor for serport is not called, and thus the port not closed.

You must implement a way to cleanly terminate your program. A signal handler may be a way. There could be others/better, depending on how you want your program to behave when it will be finished (finished as in "code complete").

[*]: I say "typical" because many programs (daemons) implement a handler for SIGINT, that they use to re-read their configuration file(s). This enables you to "refresh" the configuration of a daemon server without having to stop and then restart it.