# QApplication and SIGTERM

Tags: qt, qt5.5, sigterm, qapplication

Why doesn't QApplication handle SIGTERM (and any other) signal and exit gracefully? Are there any good reasons not to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QApplication: How to shutdown gracefully on Ctrl-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300401/qapplication-how-to-shutdown-gracefully-on-ctrl-c)

Comment: The _Why_ might be addressed to the developers of Qt. If it isn't mentioned in the doc. [Calling Qt Functions From Unix Signal Handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html), the best everybody else can do is guessing.